# Is this a good approach for building a templating/layouts system in laravel? Would it better to save data to a database?

Tags: php, database, laravel, templates, templating

I'm building a Laravel PHP application where a user will be able to create 'layouts' for pages.

To make a layout a user enters HTML in a form and optionally they may specify areas where, when creating a page that uses this layout, a WYSIWYG editor would allow an editor to add content.

What happens now is this HTML is saved in `/storage/templates/layouts` as a `.blade.php` file. The user designates the editable areas by using blade's `@yield` directive. Each editable area is wrapped with an `@section` directive and concatenated into a single `.blade.php` file and the `@extends()` directive is added, referencing the layout. Then it's saved in `/storage/templates/pages`. When a page is requested, it simply returns the view as a normal blade view `return view('templates.pages.{page_slug}');`.

In terms of performance, security and maintainability is this a good approach? Would storing this data in a database be better? Any suggestions for improving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is not good for security purposes. If I understand correctly, the user can enter blade code? Or html code which is stored in blade files? If so, they can execute PHP code on your server. For example, if I would write in my html file:

```
@php(\App\User::first()->some_data)
```

I could get all user data, delete all files and can basically control everything. I would probably store only the HTML in normal files or in the database and load them with: `{!! $userPage->htmlCode !!}` or something. So they can enter html code but not PHP / Blade code.

If you have any questions, feel free to comment!

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm going to look into storing this in the database and not processing with blade.